# Starting Local Dev Server: Does that open up computer to internet?

Tags: webpack, server, localhost

I am fairly new to development and using React and Webpack.  I am running `npm run development` to start a local server during development to see my changes and enabled hot loading to save time as well so my changes refresh.  How does this diff from someone turning their computer into a server that is accessible by anyone?  I just wanted to make sure it was safe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends if to what network interface you bind your server.
If you bind it to `0.0.0.0`, it will be accessible from all network interfaces, that means that it will available from the internet.

If it is bound to `127.0.0.1` (loopback interface), it will be accessible from localhost only.

A good video that explains it pretty well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYTG7bvpvRI (the one that I've learnt from :])